# What are some of the scriptures which talk about Human Psychology at length?

Tags: scripture, philosophy, health

So we have a group of scriptures called Darshana, which I think is possibly close to philosophy text from a Western perspective, We have scriptures for Tantra and Vigyaan, similarly what are some of the scriptures which talk about Human Psychology at length?

Comment: Psychology is a modern day field. So None

Comment: I'm guessing the literature associated with the Pratyabhijñā school come's as close to modern psychology.